# Button image not changing in MainActivity.onCreate

Tags: java, android, android-imagebutton

I have a mute button that mutes my app via `onclick`. When I return to `MainActivity` (where the button is) I use the `savedInstanceState` method to keep muted or to unmute the app (depending on what was the configuration when the user exited the activity). If the button was clicked and the app is on mute I want (when I return to `MainActivity`) the button to be shown as muted (I have different images for mute and unmute).

My code:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.mutecounterkeydefault);
     mutecounter= sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.mutecounterkey), defaultValue);
    mutebb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.muteb);
    if (mutecounter == 1) { 
        mutebb.setImageResource(R.mipmap.muteon);} //this if is not working

    mutebb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MediaPlayerPool.mute = !MediaPlayerPool.mute;
            if (mutecounter == 0) {
                mutebb.setImageResource(R.mipmap.muteon);
                mutecounter = 1;
            } else {
                mutebb.setImageResource(R.mipmap.muteoff);
                mutecounter = 0;
            }
        }
    });
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
    editor.putInt(getString(R.string.mutecounterkey), mutecounter);
    editor.apply();
```

The solution code is

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.mutecounterkeydefault);
    mutecounter= sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.mutecounterkey), defaultValue);
    mutebb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.muteb);
    if (mutecounter == 1) {
        mutebb.setImageResource(R.mipmap.muteon);
        MediaPlayerPool.mute = true;
    }

    mutebb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            if (mutecounter == 0) {
                mutebb.setImageResource(R.mipmap.muteon);
                mutecounter = 1;
                MediaPlayerPool.mute = true;
                        editor.putInt(getString(R.string.mutecounterkey), mutecounter);
            } else {
                mutebb.setImageResource(R.mipmap.muteoff);
                mutecounter = 0;
                MediaPlayerPool.mute = false;
                        editor.putInt(getString(R.string.mutecounterkey), mutecounter);


            }
            editor.apply();


        }
    });
```

Comment: `user exited the activity` you mean user exited the application?

Comment: i mean the user exited the current activity

Comment: You need to use sharedpreference , saveedinstance is used in case of activity recreation

Comment: Tried with shared preference but the "unmuted" image is still showing instead of the "mute" one

Comment: Try saving instance in Tiny Db which is shared preference .
https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're saving the `muteCounter` before the `OnClickListener` is called.

Your code will set the `onClickListener`, then immediately save the muteCounter to whatever value is held by `mutecounter` at that time, which in this case will be `0` every time.

What you need to do is this:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.mutecounterkeydefault);    
int mutecounter = sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.mutecounterkey), defaultValue);

ImageButton mutebb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.muteb);

if (mutecounter == 1) {
    mutebb.setImageResource(R.mipmap.muteon);
}

mutebb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MediaPlayerPool.mute = !MediaPlayerPool.mute;

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

        if (mutecounter == 0) {
            mutebb.setImageResource(R.mipmap.muteon);
            mutecounter = 1;


            editor.putInt(getString(R.string.mutecounterkey), mutecounter);

        } else {
            mutebb.setImageResource(R.mipmap.muteoff);
            mutecounter = 0;

            editor.putInt(getString(R.string.mutecounterkey), mutecounter);
        }

        editor.apply();
    }
});
```

We're setting the value to save to `SharedPreferences` inside the `OnClickListener` here, so that it will always be set when the button is tapped.

That way the next time the view is loaded, it will have the new value in `SharedPreferences`. The way you have it currently, you're always saving the default value to `SharedPreferences`, not updating it when the button is pressed.

Comment: I don't see your code for muting the sound. Are you muting all sound on the device or just a specific sound that you're playing?

Comment: Thanks it wokred and i fixed the other issue

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the code inside the onClick method is executed only when the button is clicked. and the code outside the onClick method is executed immediately when the activity is created. so the changes made by onClick method will not be reflected in sharedPreference because the code for saving data in preference is not get executed when the onClick method is called.

Solution:

Put the "saving data to SharedPreferences" logic inside the onClick method like this.

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.mutecounterkeydefault);
     mutecounter= sharedPref.getInt(getString(R.string.mutecounterkey), defaultValue);
    mutebb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.muteb);
    if (mutecounter == 1) { 
        mutebb.setImageResource(R.mipmap.muteon);} //this if is not working

```
mutebb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MediaPlayerPool.mute = !MediaPlayerPool.mute;
        if (mutecounter == 0) {
            mutebb.setImageResource(R.mipmap.muteon);
            mutecounter = 1;
        } else {
            mutebb.setImageResource(R.mipmap.muteoff);
            mutecounter = 0;
        }
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putInt(getString(R.string.mutecounterkey), mutecounter);
        editor.apply();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You can create a **new class** Data file like:

```
    public class DataStoreTemporary {

    ////////////////////////////////// INSTANCE //////////////////////////////////
    private static DataStoreTemporary instance = null;

    public static DataStoreTemporary getInstance() {
        if (null == instance) {
            synchronized (DataStoreTemporary.class) {
                if (null == instance) {
                    instance = new DataStoreTemporary();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }

    //Example//
    private boolean isMute = false;

    public boolean isMute() {
        return isMute;
    }

    public void setMute(boolean mute) {
        isMute = mute;
    }
}
```

And for use in your code (in Activity):

```
boolean mute = DataStoreTemporary.getInstance.isMute; //get information
DaraStoreTemporary.getInstance.setMute(mute); //to save the state
```

If you don't close the app, this should work.

Comment: This is really overkill. The point of using `SharedPreferences` is to persist through app restarts. His issue was that he wasn't saving to `SharedPreferences` inside his `onClickListener`, he was immediately saving the current value after setting the onClickListener, which would always be `0`.

Comment: @LukeWaggoner not really overkill, is easy has a file to save data than use SharedPreferences. He did not said anything about restarts, he only said about go back to main activity. Even people ask in comments about exit app but he said only exit activity. So by his question I can understand that he wanna save while using the app (like finish activity), but not necessary when it closed. So my answer is right and not overkill, really don't get it why you downvote me, but is your opinion so ok. And since he wanna save when close my answer is not what he need, but the question was not this.

Comment: You're making a whole new singleton class in order to save data that could much easier be saved using SharedPreferences. I call that overkill.

Comment: @LukeWaggoner I call SharedPreferences overkill if you don't need to save when the app is close (as I get from the question). Even for use SP more organised would be good have a class only for this. Anyway, this discussion will go to now where. But thanks for the opinion we just have different approaches.

Comment: We indeed have different approaches. Were I doing this wanting it to reset on app restart, I would use an Application class and reset the value in SP on app close. Or I would put it in a BaseActivity all Activities inherit.